# list.ToString not showing correct output

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the items in a list in to a string. but every time I convert it or display it all is shows is "TwitchIrcChar.user". If some one could help with this, it would be very helpful. sorry if noob question, but im new to lists. ive tried using convert.ToString and userlist.tostring. both gave the same output

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TwitchIrcChat
{
class User
{

    static Random random = new Random();
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsMod { get; set; }

    public User(string username)
    {
        IsMod = false;
        UserName = username;
        randomColor();
    }

    public void setColor(SolidColorBrush color)
    {
        Color = color;
    }

    private void randomColor()
    {
        var temp = Brushes.White;
        int randomColor = random.Next(0, 10);
        switch (randomColor)
        {
            case 0:
                temp = Brushes.Blue;
                break;
            case 1:
                temp = Brushes.Green;
                break;
            case 2:
                temp = Brushes.Red;
                break;
            case 3:
                temp = Brushes.Purple;
                break;
            case 4:
                temp = Brushes.Orange;
                break;
            case 5:
                temp = Brushes.Yellow;
                break;
            case 6:
                temp = Brushes.Gold;
                break;
            case 7:
                temp = Brushes.Teal;
                break;
            case 8:
                temp = Brushes.Cyan;
                break;
            case 9:
                temp = Brushes.LightBlue;
                break;
            case 10:
                temp = Brushes.Pink;
                break;
        }
        Color = temp;
    }
}

class UserList
{
    public moderation q = new moderation();
    public List<User> userList { get; set; }

    public UserList()
    {
        userList = new List<User>();
    }

    public void Add(string userName)
    {
        bool isInList = false;
        foreach (var item in userList)
        {
            if (item.UserName.Equals(userName))
            {
                isInList = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isInList)
        {
            var tempUser = new User(userName);
            userList.Add(tempUser);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string userName)
    {
        int userLocation = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < userList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (userName.Equals(userList[i].UserName))
            {
                userLocation = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            userList.RemoveAt(userLocation);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush getColor(string username)
    {
        var temp = Brushes.White;
        foreach (var item in userList)
        {
            if (item.UserName.Equals(username))
            {
                temp = item.Color;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public void setColor(string username, string color)
    {
        if (userList.Count(s => s.UserName == username) == 0)
        {
            Add(username);
        }
        var user = userList.First(s => s.UserName == username);
        var converter = new BrushConverter();
        var brush = (SolidColorBrush)converter.ConvertFromString(color);
        user.Color = brush;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        userList.Clear();
    }

    public void list()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("qweqweqweqwe");
        for (int i = 0; i < userList.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userList[i].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("qweqweqweqwe");

        }

    }

    public void AddMod(string userName)
    {
        foreach (var item in userList)
        {
           //string a = item.ToString();
           //q.writeToFile(a);
            if (item.UserName.Equals(userName))
            {

                item.IsMod = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You have to define what the string representation of `User` is by overriding `ToString()` in the `User` class. You have to tell it how you want to display a `User` explicitly, right now it's just using the default.

Comment: What do you want the "string representation" of `User` to look like?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @icemanind I this is getting the user list of a twitch channel. so if im in the channel, the string representation would be hurnhu. and sorry im learning someone elses code...

Comment: @MichaelLapan - As everyone has posted below then, you need to override the `ToString` method and have it `return UserName;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override ToString like others have suggested or if UserName is all you rally want you just do.

```
Console.WriteLine(userList[i].UserName.ToString());
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(userList[i].UserName);
```

since its already a string

Comment: This would work effectively in this one case, but if there are (or ever could be at any point in the future) any other instances where a string representation of the object could be needed then it would be better to encapsulate that logic into the object itself.  The question to ask at that point is, are you outputting the "username" to the console or are you outputting the "user" to the console?  If the latter, encapsulate the logic into the `User`.

Comment: Yes that is true however there is no reason to overide ToString if not needed.  Also in this case perhaps all he wants is UserName and in the future User.ToString should be something else like UserName + age

Comment: I am solely using this for debugging, so this works. but thanks for all the other answers! very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with lists, and everything to do with how you represent a custom object as a string.

The default behavior for `.ToString()` is exactly what you're seeing, outputting the name of the class.  .NET has no way of intuitively knowing what you mean when you want to see an object as a string.  You need to explicitly provide that logic by [overriding `.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154.aspx) on your object.

For example, if you just want to see the user's name, it could be something as simple as:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return UserName;
}
```

Essentially, the question you need to ask yourself is, "Am I outputting a property on the User, or am I outputting the User itself?"  If the latter, you'd definitely want to encapsulate that logic into a `.ToString()` override, since that logic may change over time.  For example, if you ever want the string representation of a `User` to also show if the `User` is a "mod" (say, for example, with a `*` character), you would just add that in the override:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}",
        UserName,
        IsMod ? "(*)" : string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `ToString()` method in your class and return the desired string in that method. For instance if you want to return `UserName` when `ToString()` is called on an instance of User, you can do it like this:

```
public class User 
{
   public string UserName {get;set;}
   public override string ToString()
   {
        return UserName;
   }
}
```

If you don't do this, the default `ToString()` will return the name of the object's type.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `ToString()` (inherited from `System.Object`) is to display the type name. If you want to change this behavior you must override `ToString`:

```
class User
{
    ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return UserName + (IsMod ? " (moderator)" : "");
    }
}
```

`ToString` is used automatically by `Console.WriteLine`, so you simply call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(userList[i]);
```

You can also add objects directly to listboxes for instance, as those use `ToString` as well in order to display the items.

```
listBox1.Items.Add(user);
```

Comment: Curious why this was down voted?  This is a more appropriate use of overriding ToString() than to simply spit out a single property.

Comment: Looks like someone either serial-downvoted answers involving `.ToString()` overrides and missed one, or someone serial-downvoted competing answers and missed one.  (Or someone randomly came to this question and randomly downvoted answers.  Either way, it's not something to be taken personally.)